# 'AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifest' does not exist

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest

I was importing facebook sdk when I got this error. I added `manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'` as instructed but still getting error. Would be greatful if anyone can help me in removing the mentioned error: 'AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifest' does not exist.

```js
gradle.properties

# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=23.0.2
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=15
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=23
```

```css
build.gradle inside "app" folder

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sam.freebies"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/bolts.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}
```

```html
Root directory build.gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
Why are you using this. try after removing it.

Comment: Its auto generated. Even after removing it, the error shows @warlock

Comment: On removing the whole "sourceSets" now its good.